# Specify program to run cmake tests with

Tags: testing, cmake

I am crosscompiling a CMake project with emscripten to JavaScript. This already works well. Now I would like to enable the tests in JavaScript. How can I tell CMake that it should run every test with the Nodejs interpreter instead of running it directly on the commandline. So instead of running `./testname` CMake should run `node ./testname.js`.

The tests are simply added with `ADD_TEST()`. Running the tests by hand with Nodejs on the commandline already works fine.

Does anyone know how to archive that in CMake?

Answer (score 0):

How about using some of the options provided by `add_test()`?

[http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:add_test](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aadd_test)

`add_test(NAME <name> [CONFIGURATIONS [Debug|Release|...]]
           [WORKING_DIRECTORY dir]
           COMMAND <command> [arg1 [arg2 ...]])`

What have you tried?

Comment: I did not try anything yet (except from testing whether the tests are generally executable by Nodejs) because I didn't know where to start. I know that I could edit every test adding some sort of custom command but that is not applyable for a bigger project (which I'm working on) with hundrets of tests. I hope that it's possible to generally manipulate how Cmake runs tests for a specific configuration..

Comment: Why not add a macro which adds a number of tests with whatever executable you ned to run? Then call this macro from your CmakeLists?